# Guessing list of google kind of functionality

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wanted to add a functionality in a text-box that if someone is typing a name and I already have a list of names than just like `Google Search` gives us some guess list at the bottom of the text box related to the letters we entered in the text-box I can also give the same list populated with all the names that are in the name list.
 Is this possible ? 
and if yes then where should I start from ?
Thank You

Comment: try `jQuery.ui.autocomplete` plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I have a compulsion to use JavaScript or Ajax cant use jquery